# Did the writers know from the beginning who Red John was?

Tags: the-mentalist

Rewatching The Mentalist lately, I realized that we actually meet Red John quite early.

The true identity of Red John was revealed years later.

That made me wonder. **Did the writers know the identity of Red John from the beginning or was it decided later in the show?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Doesn't look like it, [according to series creator/exec producer Bruno Heller](http://www.tvguide.com/news/mentalist-red-john-1073838/) in November 2013:

> "Xander is a wonderfully subtle actor who can go deep — deep enough to
>   be our Red John," says series creator/exec producer Bruno Heller, **who
>   says he selected McAllister to be his Big Bad "about a year ago, after
>   carefully weighing all other options**. McAllister made the most sense.
>   He had the perfect cover job as the sheriff of Napa, where he was the
>   master of his domain. No one ever questioned his whereabouts. He
>   didn't have to answer to anyone. He needed that freedom and the quiet
>   loneliness of the countryside to do his thing as Red John."

[More from Bruno Heller](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/live-feed/mentalist-red-johns-fate-revealed-659592) in The Hollywood Reporter (also November 2013):

> It was important to "give a real emotional, pleasing end to that
>   story," creator-showrunner Bruno Heller told reporters, **admitting that
>   the ultimate Red John identity slowly "emerged" over the last few
>   seasons**. "For me it was about giving Patrick Jane exactly what he's
>   wanted for all these years. He wanted revenge and he got it. I think
>   that's what the audience wanted, so that's what we gave them."

[In Entertainment Weekly](http://www.ew.com/article/2013/11/24/the-mentalist-red-john-interview) (November 2013):

> When did Heller decide Red John’s identity?
>
> Bruno Heller: I’m not
>   sure. **It kind of just emerged over the last couple years. There was
>   always three or four possibilities.** And it just happened, really. It
>   seemed like the natural correct choice.